# CodeIgniter MySQL query using too much memory - How can I use MySQL's SSCursor?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, memory-management

I'm working on an application using CodeIgniter for database access. The application issues queries like these: `$this->db->query("SELECT fields_list FROM table_name");`
But the table has hundreds of thousands of records.

CodeIgniter tries to load the whole result set into memory, causing the script to reach memory limit.

The way around this issue is to use libmysqlclient API's SSCursor but I can't see any example of CodeIgniter using SSCursor. Is there a way to use MySQL's SSCursor in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM? Maybe Doctrine? It handles such situations a little better than CodeIgniter's native db class.

Comment: No problem. I don't install CI by itself anymore...I prepackage it with Doctrine almost always. It may be overkill on some projects, but my development is sped up quite a bit. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop and limit the number of records retrieved in a single query.

Get a count of total records in the table. Then do a:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=COUNT_OF_RECORDS; $i+=1000) {
     $sql = "SELECT fields_list FROM table_name LIMIT $i,1000";
}
```